# iOS: Send basic http post request and parse JSON response

Tags: ios, json, http-post

I am starting out in `ios` from `android` and I am trying to figure out how to send a basic http post request for a registration page and then getting the http response and read errors that have been returned using the `json_encode` function in php. Example:

```
if(minMaxRange(5,25,$username))
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_CHAR_LIMIT",array(5,25));
        $data = array('userCharLimit' => 'Your username must be between 5 and 25 characters in length');
        print (json_encode($data)); 
    }
```

I am been searching around `stackoverflow` and `google` and I can only find decent documentation on sending `JSON`and returning `JSON`. I kind of have an idea on how to send the http post request but I am clueless on retrieving the values from the response.

This is how I retrieve the `JSON` values after sending the post in `Android`:

```
// Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            if (object.has("userCharLimit")) {
                String userCharLimit = object.getString("userCharLimit");
                error = error + userCharLimit;
            }
private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String rLine = "";
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            answer.append(rLine);
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return answer;
```

Is ios going to be relatively similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/how-to-make-http-request-from-iphone-and-parse-json-result/) is a good link on retrieving all values from JSON and grabbing specific values.

In order to retrieve POST data you will need to edit the code slightly.

The 'connectionDidFinishLoading' method is where you will see how to grab values.

This really helped me out. Just passing on the discovery.

Best of luck!

EDIT** Incase the link ever goes down. Author of the code below is "JR" from https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com

```
@interface spike1ViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *responseData;
@end

@implementation spike1ViewController

@synthesize responseData = _responseData;

- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    NSLog(@"viewdidload");
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data]; 
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAbgGH36jnyow0MbJNP4g6INkMXqgKFfHk"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {        
    [self.responseData appendData:data]; 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {    
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    // show all values
    for(id key in res) {

        id value = [res objectForKey:key];

        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

        NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
    }

    // extract specific value...
    NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"results"];

    for (NSDictionary *result in results) {
        NSString *icon = [result objectForKey:@"icon"];
        NSLog(@"icon: %@", icon);
    }

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

UPDATE**

To avoid receiving deprecation warnings in apps targeting iOS 9 and up, you may use NSURLSession and it's block style format. Here is the idea:

```
_request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL TO POST DATA TO"]];
[_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[_request addValue:post forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];
NSData *data = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[_request setHTTPBody:data];
[_request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *serviceConnection = [session dataTaskWithRequest:_request
                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                                 {

                                                     if (!error) {

                                                         //BEGIN PARSING RESPONSE.

                                                     }else{

                                                         //AN ERROR OCCURED. HANDLE APPROPRIATELY.
                                                     }

                                                 }];
        [serviceConnection resume];
```